# Algorithm for probability of following a path

Tags: ios, algorithm

I'm developing an iOS application that needs to determine the probability that a user is following a given path.

If they are not following the path, I'd like to give them the option to recalculate.

This should be a relatively simple algorithm, for inputs I have a location (x,y) and n paths (two x,y points).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [**Dijkstra's algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find shortest distance between two points? What I think is you should always feed the current location of vehicle as it will show the recalculated value if taken a wrong turn and show it in graph. Hope it helps.